# Web site brows form specified device

Tags: c#, spring, security, pki, websecurity

I want to force some of my web application users to access from specified PC/device (their pc's mac address , private IP already stored at database). How i implement this?

Comment: Is your website publicly hosted?

Comment: yes my web application publicly hosted.

Comment: You mean client MAC addresses and IP addresses that can be changed at will?  I hope this isn't part of your security plan!

Comment: When user accesses your website, the request will come to website via one one or more network paths/route/ISPs. That will not reveal the real IP/private IP of the user's computer.

Comment: @garethTheRed thanks, yest it is not part of my security plan.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thanks, actually we can install service/hardware those pc and get information from service to get information via javascript. But client can manipulate it  easily. i need more secure plan.